# Razor generating HTML on a single line in if block

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code in my Razor view

```
    @Html.LabelFor(t=>t.Name)
    @Html.LabelFor(t=>t.Name)

    @if (true)
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Name)
        @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Name)
    }
```

The two blocks of code generate different HTML.

```
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <label for="Name">Name</label>

<label for="Name">Name</label><label for="Name">Name</label>
```

This is also displayed differently (in Chrome and IE), one has a gap between the two elements, one does not:

[image: Rendered HTML]

Is this a bug in Razor/MVC? Or should I not be using @Html helpers within if blocks?

Changing to the following makes them both display the same but is not ideal.

```
    @Html.LabelFor(t=>t.Name)
    @Html.LabelFor(t=>t.Name)

    @if (true)
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Name)@Html.Raw("\n")
        @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Name)
    }
```

## Update

Placing the Html helpers within a `<div>` fixes the problem.

```
@Html.LabelFor(t=>t.Name)
@Html.LabelFor(t=>t.Name)

@if (true)
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Name)
        @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Name)
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Razor suppresses whitespace in code blocks.

So as you found on your own, writing some kind of whitespace character to the output manually would be the only way to simulate the code that you have written outside the code block.

Comment: Is there any way to suppress this other than to wrap the helpers in a <div>?

Comment: Maybe by wrapping it in `@<text>` ?  I haven't tried so I can't say for sure.  But `@<text>` is supposed to treat everything in it as if they were not in a code block.  Worth a try.